# KendoGrid not appearing in KendoWindow

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-window

I am trying to have a grid show up in a kendoWindow, but the grid is not showing up.
This is my html

```
<div id="ShowPrompts">
    <div id="PromptsGrid">

    </div>
</div>
```

I have this all happening when a row gets clicked in a detailGrid, it passes the GroupID and OptionID, this is the function

```
function GetThePromptsData(gid, oid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: URLParams.PromptsData + "?globalgroupID=" + gid + "&optionid=" + oid,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            CreatePromptsGrid(data);
            ShowPromptsPopUp();
        }
    });
}
```

and this is the ShowPromptsPopUp() function

```
function ShowPromptsPopUp() {
    $("#ShowPrompts").kendoWindow({
        width: "300px",
        height: "300px",
        title: "Option Prompts",
        visible: false,
        modal: true,
        actions: [
            "Close"
        ]
    }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
}
```

I have checked and there is a data in the JsonResult, but doesn't want to show up in the window.

**EDIT**

I ran this again and the window won't appear when called as I show it, so I removed the ShowPromptsPopUp() from the GetThePromptsData() and placed it in the change event of the detailGrid, the window appears but still no grid in the window.

In the detailGrid change event, the order is this

```
GetThePromptsData(globalID, optionID);
ShowPromptsPopUp();
```

**EDIT 2**

```
var promptGrid,
CreatePromptsGrid = function (promptsData) {
    promptGrid = $("#PromptsGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            promptsData
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "PromptID",
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "Question", title: "Question" },
            { field: "DefaultAnswer", title: "Answer" }
        ],
        change: function (e) {

        },
        scrollable: true,
        pageable: false,
        selectable: "row"
    }).data("KendoGrid");
}
```

Comment: You have to pass the content to the dialog either by using the content(html) or content{ url : <SOME_URL>}.

Comment: @Irb hmmm...ok, so i should use a partialview then? if so will the view actually fit properly in the size of the window?

Comment: You can set a (min)height/width, however, using center().open(), as you are above, will adjust the width and height to accommodate your partial view.

Comment: please post CreatePromptsGrid function as well

Comment: @JoseTuttu, I just added the CreatePromptsGrid

Answer (score 0):

```
I have modified the code little and its working. please check:
function GetThePromptsData() {
   /* $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        }
    });*/
    data =[ {
    PromptID:1,
    Question:"test 1",
    DefaultAnswer:"test answer 1" 

    },
    {
    PromptID:2,
    Question:"test 2",
    DefaultAnswer:"test answer 2"    

    },
    ]
     CreatePromptsGrid(data);
      ShowPromptsPopUp();
}

function ShowPromptsPopUp() {
    $("#ShowPrompts").kendoWindow({
        width: "300px",
        height: "300px",
        title: "Option Prompts",
        visible: false,
        modal: true,
        actions: [
            "Close"
        ]
    }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
}

var promptGrid,
CreatePromptsGrid = function (promptsData) {
    promptGrid = $("#PromptsGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data:promptsData
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "PromptID",
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "Question", title: "Question" },
            { field: "DefaultAnswer", title: "Answer" }
        ],
        change: function (e) {

        },
        scrollable: true,
        pageable: false,
        selectable: "row"
    }).data("KendoGrid");
}

GetThePromptsData();
```